# How to turn off wordwrap in Microsoft word 2003

Tags: word-wrap

Such a basic requirement is not found in any of the menus.

Comment: As an alternative I would suggest Notepad, or if you still want the formatting options go for Wordpad. Both are packaged in any Windows installation, and both have the option for turning off word wrap

Comment: If you're trying to get Word to word-wrap, you're using it for the wrong purpose.

Comment: @SLaks: Do you want to rethink that comment?

Comment: @​Jason: ​​​What? ​

Comment: @SLaks: Word-wrap is exactly what you always do want with a word processor, like Word.  It is text editors where you may want to turn it off.

Comment: @paradroid: I think I meant to **not** word-wrap.

Answer (score 3):

Word holds document text in pages.
Disabling word wrap would cause the text to fall off of the page.

This is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is a text editor, not a word processor like Word, which is meant for formatting documents to fit on certain paper sizes.

Notepad comes as standard on Windows, but there are probably hundreds to choose from.  [Here's a non-exhaustive list.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors)

Answer (score 2):

In the bottom left corner are 4 icons. One of them will turn off word wrap *just on the page*. It will still wrap the text to the screen though. I believe the one to try is the Web Layout, but without 2003 anymore, I can't test